# Problema con buscar elementos cargados por .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ando experimentando con una nueva plataforma de foros y me ha surgido un problemilla: He intentado cargar, por medio de `load`, una sección del foro para así extraer su id y colocarlo en la página actual. Lo que pasa es que, por algún motivo, al buscar el elemento (en la sección de extraerle el id) simplemente no lo encuentra.

He leído por ahí que debo usar `on`, pero por más que lo intento no termino de configurarlo como debe, por consiguiente vengo aquí a pedir ayuda.

Éste es el código base, sin los usos de los `on`, el cual asigna siempre *undefined* por el motivo que ya he explicado.

```
var topfor = $('#ST .activeuserstrip:nth-last-child(2) strong a').attr('href');
$('#actualfor').load(topfor + ' .forum-header');
var actfor = $('.forum-header').attr('id');
$('#ST .maintitle')[0].setAttribute('id', actfor);
```

Y éste es el HTML simplificado:

```
<body id="ST" class="user-1 mod-1 admin-1">
    <div id="forum-hidden">
        <div id="actualfor">
            <div id="forum-1" class="forum-header">
                <div class="forum-cover">
                    <div class="forum-name">
                        A Test Forum
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="forum-body">
        <div id="forum-center">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="innerwrapper">
                    <div class="tableborder">
                        <div class="maintitle" id="undefined">
                            &nbsp;<span class="topic-title">Prueba</span>, Prueba</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="activeuserstrip" align="center">
                        <!--SOCIAL_BOOKMARKS--> « <a href="URL 1">Next Oldest</a> | <strong><a href="URL 2">A Test Forum</a></strong> | <a href="URL 3">Next Newest</a> »
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar también el código HTML? Por favor

Comment: HTML añadido :D.

Comment: Cierto, se me ha pasado :/. Ya está añadido.

Comment: Hola lady, sigo sin ver el atributo href del elemento, lo cual se deduce que es imposible que tu código funcione.

Comment: Oh, esa sección funciona sin problemas por que si no #actualfor no tendría contenido dentro xD. He quitado las url para facilitar la lectura y tal.

¿Las pongo?.

Comment: Ahh si, disculpas, no me fijé bien jajaja

Comment: DE todos el selector que estás usando es imposible que coincida con el atributo, en todo caso sería así: `$('#ST .activeuserstrip a').attr('href');`

Comment: Si usara esadirección apuntaría a los tres links que tiene .activeuserstrip, no al del medio que tiene la dirección que necesito xD. De todos modos, como ya he dicho, esa sección del código es la que funciona perfectamente y carga lo que debería (contenido del #actualfor que ya he dicho), el problema está en sacar el id de lo que se obtiene al cargar y, por ende, siempre da undefined.

Comment: el nth-child debes aplicarselo al tag <a> es decir así: $('#ST .activeuserstrip a:nth-child(2)').attr('href');

Comment: No, repito, ese código ya va, lo que pasa es que como está simplificado ves ahí un fallo que realment eno está puesto que, en el completo, bajo ese segmento hay otro bloque para dirigirse, direcamente, al ya mentado xD. Remarco: El problema está en las dos últimas líneas del js, no las dos primeras.

Comment: que hace exactamente esta linea `$('#actualfor').load(topfor + ' .forum-header');` que no logro entenderla, cargas un contenido de la url generada?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedo comprender es que estas extrayendo el id de la clase `.forum-header`.

Ahora, el uso de los `on` es bastante sencillo:
Por lo general siempre coloco todo dentro del evento de cargar la pagina. cuando la pagina este lista

```
$(document).on("ready", function({

    $("#myId").on("Click", function(){
        var id_clickeado = $(this).attr("id");

    });

});
```

Comment: No termino de seguirlo... De todos modos he añadido el HTML del asunto para ver si ayuda :D.

Answer (score 0):

El HTML que colocas es despues de haber ejecutado $('#actualfor').load, el cual pide al server el siguiente fragmento de HTML que es colocado dentro del `<div id="actualfor>`

```
        <div id="forum-1" class="forum-header">
            <div class="forum-cover">
                <div class="forum-name">
                    A Test Forum
                </div>
            </div>
```

Pero cuando ejecutas las siguientes dos líneas el `<div id="actualfor>` aún está vacío ya que es cargado mediante un ajax (el load)

```
$('#actualfor').load(topfor + ' .forum-header'); //Pides el .forum-header al servidor
var actfor = $('.forum-header').attr('id'); //El servidor aún no te contesta, por lo tanto no existe .forum-header y regresa Undefined
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es agregar la funcion de callback del **load**

```
$('#actualfor').load(topfor + ' .forum-header', function(){
    var actfor = $('.forum-header').attr('id');
    $('#ST .maintitle')[0].setAttribute('id', actfor);
});
```

[Documentación del .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function)